# Android Studio - How can I create a Card View?

Tags: android

I am having trouble creating a card view in Android Studio, I am creating an App on Nexus 7.  Please help me with a step-by-step guide to create a working card view :)

A

Comment: This is not how stackoverflow works. You should have googled first. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple to create card view in android :

very first you have to add dependency in gradle:

compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'

and you have too add card view in XML:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_viewspOffer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0.5dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
  >

<TextView
     android:id="@+id/test"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:maxLines="5"
     android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="TEST" />
  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Inspite of textview you can put all the android components or layouts as per your design need

Answer (score 1):

You can create card view as follow:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card_viewspOffer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0.5dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
  >
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this to build.gradle to include the card view stuff into your project

   `compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'`
2. Now you can add the card view like any other widget

   `<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
   ...`